# Expo Location Module doesn't return a speed

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I've written a React Native / Expo app that uses the Expo Location module.

In it, it uses the Location.getCurrentPositionAsync to get a JSON dictionary with position, speed and heading.

Yet, whatever I do, the "speed" portion seems to come in as "zero". This is true on both Android and iOS. I'm getting the data like this:

```
let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({accuracy: 6});
```

And I get an object like this:

```
Object {
  "coords": Object {
    "accuracy": 13.522000312805176,
    "altitude": 5,
    "heading": 0,
    "latitude": 37.4219983,
    "longitude": -122.084,
    "speed": 0,
  },
  "mocked": false,
  "timestamp": 1550650746000,
}
```

Does the Expo Location module simply not collect GPS speeds? Or am I calling it wrong?

Thanks
Robert